# Android wevbiew show Google Maps locked until touch pressed

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, webview

Using the android webview component for show Google Maps through API v3 it seem all the map "engine" is locked until touch is pressed. I tested the default browser also. If I go to the google maps web site and start move the map touching the screen is there always a point where there is a gray area of the map still not loaded. In standard Desktop browser this "missing" part is loaded instantly but under android webview this part remain unloaded for all the time of touch pression. If I stop touch the screen this missing image is loaded. This is a very bad behaviour mainly because the same problem happen also with javascript code. I need to get the google maps api "center_changed" event on real time but cause this problem the event is not delivered for all the time the touch is pressed (moving the map). The event is delivedered only on touch leave. Someone noted this strange behaviour and know a workaround for enable "real time" interaction through javascript code?

Thank you

Comment: it depends of data transfer, not really related with webview or maps, if you connect maps app or browse it by limiting data connection you will experience same gray issue when loading...

Comment: Thank you for the info. I can accept the limitation regarding map image loading but same limit for javascript events is really bad for my purposes. There is absolutely no way for a workaround covering javascript only?

Comment: Consider to have some `splash screen` to load the data first.

Comment: I need a real time control for all the time the user intercact with the map, not only in startup phase...